# prevent json.Marshal time.Time removing trailing zeros

Tags: go

I have code similar to the following

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Message struct {
    Time time.Time `json:"timestamp,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z07:00", "2017-05-01T15:04:05.630Z")
    msg := Message{
        Time: t,
    }
    bs, _ := json.Marshal(msg)
    fmt.Println(string(bs[:]))
}
```

This prints

```
{"timestamp":"2017-05-01T15:04:05.63Z"}
```

How can I make json marshalling keep the trailing 0?  I.e., to print this?

```
{"timestamp":"2017-05-01T15:04:05.630Z"}
```

Edit:

Here's the playground https://play.golang.org/p/9p3kWeiwu2

Comment: To have that level of control you'll probably need to define your own type based on `time.Time` and implement your own version of `MarshalJSON` for that type.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Presumably a receiver expects 3 decimal points of precision? Could you fudge a little, and just make sure you never have a zero in that spot by adding `0.001` seconds?  That would hurt accuracy a bit (whether that matters depends on your application), but might make the rest of your code easier.

Comment: Well, adding 0.001 seconds still won't ensure you never have .000, since it causes X.999 to roll up to (X+1).000.

Comment: In case you need this for `TO_TIMESTAMP` function in PostgreSQL, try instead casting to `timestamptz`. For example:

`select '2021-07-29T14:12:28Z'::timestamptz;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

time.Time always marshals to RFC 3339, only including sub-second precision if present: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.MarshalJSON

You can write your own custom version using a named time.Time type, or you can define a custom marshal function for your structure, or you can make your structure hold a string in that place instead.  In any case, if you want to use the same format, but including trailing zeros, you need to use a modified version of the RFC3339Nano constant.

Its value is: `"2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"`.

The 9's at the end mean "include until the rightmost non-zero value, omit after that".  If you change those 9's to 0's, it will always include them.  For example, if you always want millisecond precision (and nothing after that, regardless of whether it's non-zero or not), you would use:

`"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z07:00"`

If you feed that to Format() on your time.Time value, you'll get out the string you want, and can thus include it in the JSON.

Functioning example: https://play.golang.org/p/oqwnma6odw

Comment: "only including sub-second precision if present": so you can use `mytime.Truncate(1 * time.Second)` to drop anything sub-second and then you have a time that will serialise out without millis, micros, nanos, etc.

Comment: Yes, though you could just as easily do that by using a format string without the subsecond precision, like `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00`.

Comment: yep that's a good solution if you're `fmt.Print()`ing or `log.Printf()`ing it, but in my case I was serialising out to JSON, so had to `mytime.Truncate()` before the serialisation. It's probably better to use a specific format string if that's an option vs permanently dropping precision off the `time.Date` struct.

Comment: Could also implement a JSON marshaller with your specified format.  Ex: https://goplay.space/#3SQ5zR5B8x0